# Django Rest Framework reverse and SimpleRouter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

How do I use DRF's `reverse` to call a complex URL from `SimpleRouter`?

My URL is at two places, one for teams, and one for games, as follows:

league.urls:

```
url(r'^team/', include('teams.urls')),
```

team.urls:

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'game', GameViewSet, 'games')
```

I'm trying to `reverse` the url to update a game. Based on the DRF SimpleRouter, this should be "/team/{pk}/game/{pk}"

My test is calling:

```
url = reverse('games-detail', args=[team.pk, game.pk])
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: redefinition of group name u'pk' as group 2; was group 1
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring them as `kwargs` and calling the URL that way?

Comment: @AronYsidoro thanks - this may be the problem. Would I just call url = reverse('teams-detail', kwargs= { 'pk': game.team.pk, 'pk': game.pk }) On both levels I'm using the pk to identify the team/game. Is this a problem or is there another way to call the URL using kwargs?

This doesn't work - gives me the same error as before. So either I'm missing something or there must be a better way to call this `reverse` :). Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

YPCrumble, you would want to call the `URL` with distinct `kwargs`. The `URL` regex works in a way to handle `kwargs`. So for example:

```
# python reverse url
url = reverse('games-detail', kwargs={'team_pk': 1, 'group_pk':1})

# url regex
url(
    r'^team/(?P<team_pk>\d+)/group/(?P<group_pk>\d+)/$',
    view.SimpleRouterDetailView.as_view(),
    name='games-detail'
)
```

Comment: -detail and -list is a big gotcha for me.
Is this mentioned somewhere in the documentation, or how I suppose to know about that syntax?

Comment: @AlexZamai it is mentioned here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be related to the use of named groups in URL patterns. Using the `args` parameter in the `reverse` function, it's causing a conflict with the named groups in URL pattern.

To address this issue, we can use the `kwargs` parameter in the `reverse` function to pass the values for the named groups. Here's example:

```py
url = reverse('games-detail', kwargs={'team_pk': team.pk, 'pk': game.pk})
```

For more comprehension:

1. [reverse in rest_framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/#reverse_lazy)
2. [router in rest_framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#customizing-dynamic-routes)